# QA Instance ("shard") for Firebase

Tags: firebase, android-testing, firebase-realtime-database

What is the recommended approach for creating alternate datasets in Firebase that I can test against, eg if I wanted to test new schemas? I see three options (any others?):

1. Create a separate qa "app"
2. Add a top-level "instance" node (eg "prod" and "qa1" "qa2" etc) within my single production firebase instance and switch in code
3. Local Firebase server as described here https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-04-24-end-to-end-testing-firebase-server.html

So (3) seems great for unit testing but i'm not sure if it would work well for larger scale QA tests. I'm also not sure if that's the official recommendation to set up a local firebase instance (pls advise, I need this for unit tests!)

(1) seems second-safest but I'm not sure if it would be considered inappropriate by the firebase team (ie taking up "free" accounts)

Comment: predictably, i've now spent a few hours playing with solution (3). i took two approaches: doing it directly as instructed in the links and also found a node gradle pluging so i could set up the download of the server and its startup via gradle tasks. In both cases I got stuck with an error, asked as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309193/local-firebase-server-node-throws-firebase-gooffline-is-not-a-function

Comment: btw Frank, now that you guys (firebase) have been part of google for a while, any plans to add official codelab on unit/e2e testing locally (akin to how google has the local app engine server so we can write e2e tests)? thx