# Local Firebase Server node throws "Firebase.goOffline is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, android-testing, firebase-realtime-database

This is probably user error on my part (i'm unfamiliar with nodejs so just fumbling my way around).

I get the below when I follow the instructions on https://github.com/urish/firebase-server and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html

when I run `firebase-server.cmd -p 5555 -v`
I am running this so I can unit-test.

```
TypeError: this.Firebase.goOffline is not a function
    at Object.FirebaseServer ([...]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-server\index.js:50:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-server\bin\firebase-server.js:21:2)
    at after ([...]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-server\node_modules\cli\cli.js:1057:18)
    at Object.cli.main ([...]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-server\node_modules\cli\cli.js:1062:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-server\bin\firebase-server.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

Comment: Which version of firebase server do you have installed?

Comment: i simply followed the instructions and did "npm install --save-dev firebase-server" i assume that will give me the 'latest' one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have the new version of the Firebase client library, which has some breaking API changes. Until `firebase-server` is updated to support the new client library API, you should be able to work around this issue by explicitly installing the older client library version:

```
npm install --save-dev firebase@2.4.2
```

Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks urish, any ETA on the update (so i can switch to latest eventually)?

Comment: You can track the progress here: https://github.com/urish/firebase-server/pull/51

Comment: btw Uri, now that you guys (firebase) have been part of google for a while, any plans to add official codelab on unit testing locally (akin to how google has the local app engine server so we can write unit tests)? any ideas if that's in the works? thx

Comment: So, firebase-server should now support 3.0.0 as of the latest release. As for the 2nd question - as I am not working for google or the Firebase team, I have no ideas about their plans. You can try to ping @puf with the question

Comment: wow urish, this entire time i thought you worked for firebase, my respect for you grows ha, thanks so much for writing firebase-server!